# How to get CPU utilization using Java 11

Tags: java, cpu-usage, java-11

I'm trying to get CPU utilization or usage using Java 11.

My expectation is the average percentage of total usage, I don't really have any interest in the number of cores or thread available on the CPU.

In simple term on 80% the CPU is very busy, and on 10% is more or less idling.

**How do I get this?**

I've been trying a couple of suggestions from stackoverflow.

**Option 1.** Using `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` is not good, anything `com.sun` is old and should be avoided.

**Option 2.** There is a 3rd party `org.hyperic.sigar.CpuInfo` which seems to be old and no longer maintained project. The result of `cpuInfo.getVendor(), cpuInfo.getModel()` below is `null null`. That gives me confidence (sacarsm).

```
protected void getCPUUtilization4() {
        CpuInfo cpuInfo =  new CpuInfo();
        System.out.println(String.format("    CpuInfo: %s %s", cpuInfo.getVendor(), cpuInfo.getModel()));
    }
```

**Option 3.** Built-in inside Java `java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean`. The problem with this option is the `osBean.getSystemLoadAverage()` is a `double` value. When my cpu is not busy ~ `1.3` , and when my CPU is busy reached up to ~`2.9`. The `osBean.getAvailableProcessors()` returns `8`. I'm pretty sure it's an Intel Quad core with total of 8 threads. Doesn't matter, how do I make sense of these numbers?

```
protected double getCPUUtilization5() {
        OperatingSystemMXBean osBean =
            ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        if (startSystemAverage == null) {
            startSystemAverage = osBean.getSystemLoadAverage();
            peakSystemAverage = osBean.getSystemLoadAverage();
        }
        if (peakSystemAverage < osBean.getSystemLoadAverage()) {
            peakSystemAverage = osBean.getSystemLoadAverage();
        }
        
        double sysAvg = osBean.getSystemLoadAverage();
        logger.info("    getCPUUtilization5: "+ sysAvg + " num of processors: "+ osBean.getAvailableProcessors());
        return sysAvg;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

With the introduction of the module system, the type `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` has become [part of the official API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html), but for modular software, there must be a declared dependency to the module [`jdk.management`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/jdk.management/module-summary.html) rather than just [`java.management`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.management/module-summary.html).

So you can officially use

```java
double cpuLoad = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(
    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean.class).getCpuLoad();
```

but it’s also possible to access the JMX attribute dynamically, to avoid a strong code dependency:

```java
try {
    double cpuLoad = (Double)ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()
        .getAttribute(new ObjectName("java.lang:type=OperatingSystem"), "CpuLoad");
    …
} catch (JMException ex) {
    System.getLogger(CPULoad.class.getName()).log(System.Logger.Level.ERROR, "", ex);
}
```

<sup>Prior to JDK 14, use [`getSystemCpuLoad()` or `"SystemCpuLoad"`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getSystemCpuLoad()) instead of [`getCpuLoad()` resp. `"CpuLoad"`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getCpuLoad())</sup>

This will not force the availability of the extension, but use it when available.

---

The *system* load average is, simply said, the average number of processes competing for the CPU. So for a single CPU system, you can say, a value of more than one not only means that the CPU was entirely busy, but the runnable tasks would have used more CPU resources when they were available.

For *n* CPUs or cores, you could say a similar thing when the system load reached the value *n*, but mind that this is only an average. So with a load value of *n* there still could have been a peek load where more than *n* application competed for the CPU, followed by some under-utilization of the CPU cores. But with enough sample values or a sufficiently high sampling rate, you can say that a value of *n* or higher implies a CPU usage saturation.